# Example of using image_proc/resize in ROS2 Foxy

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I have not been able to find an example of using image_proc/resize in ROS2 Foxy.
Can someone give me a usage example from the command line?

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373008/example-of-using-image_proc/resize-in-ros2-foxy./) by [joseecm](https://answers.ros.org/users/44853/joseecm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2021-03-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was confused by this as well. The answer appears in the CMake file: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/ros2/image_proc/CMakeLists.txt

Summary:

The `image_proc` executable contains 2 nodes: RectifyNode and DebayerNode. Example usage:

```
ros2 run image_proc image_proc
```

You can use various `--ros-args` to remap topics as needed.

To use ResizeNode you will need to write a launch file. This example might be helpful: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/ros2/image_proc/launch/image_proc.launch.py

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2021-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0